# Accessing a nested value inside of a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an issue getting some basic JavaScript running. I just recently started with JavaScript, so I haven't come close to fully grasping it yet. What I want to achieve is return the value of an option selector inside a div of a form/table.

I am utilzing Google Tag Manager to send data to Google Analytics and trying to use the built-in auto-event listeners along with custom JavaScript macros.

Basically, there are three different selectors that all have different values. These are all inside a table with selections in `<select>`.

How could I use JavaScript to get the selected value from each of the three different selectors?

The issue I am struggling with is the fact that the selectors themselves have no ID to separate them apart, but the parent element atleast has a unique div id.

I'll try to give a visualization on how it looks:

```
<form>
  <div id="selection1">
   <table ... >
    <select>
     <option>Option 1</option>
     <option>Option 2</option>
     <option>Option 3</option>
   </select>
  </table>
 </div>

  <div id="selection2">
   <table ... >
    <select>
     <option>Option 1</option>
     <option>Option 2</option>
     <option>Option 3</option>
   </select>
  </table>
 </div>

  <div id="selection3">
   <table ... >
    <select>
     <option>Option 1</option>
     <option>Option 2</option>
     <option>Option 3</option>
   </select>
  </table>
 </div>
</form>
```

How would I be able to retrieve the values from the different options and that are selected? I have tried this, and it works:

```
function () {
var option = document.GetElementsByTagName("select")[0].value; 
return option;
}
```

But then I'd need to set this up for each of the three different selections you can choose something from. I am just not savvy enough to figure out how to write a JavaScript that can calculate what someone chose in the three different options and return its values.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, first let's improve your code:

1. Never ever use spaces in an id (id="NoSpacesAllowed")
2. Spaces in class names are used to define multiple classes (class="class1 class2 class3")
   3.You should always provide a value attribute within an option tag. 
   `<option value="xy">This is some random text</option>` 
    
   Still, these values are changeable by any user so you may read modified values 
   (Some people like me often modify such cliend code in order to see if it breaks any functionality)
   Never ever store such values directly into a database! **Check if the contents (or values) are valid, otherwise you may get biiiiig proplems. And I mean biiiiiiiig problems**!

General approach:

```
var selects = document.getElementById("myselect");
var selectedValue = selects.options[selects.selectedIndex].value;// will gives u "xy"
var selectedText = selects.options[selects.selectedIndex].text;// gives u "This is some random text" but you should not use this<br><br>
```

You may want to use something like that:

```
    var selects = document.querySelector("#selection1 select"); //This will return the first <select> inside the specified id. You may need to adjust that selector...

var selectedText = selects.options[selects.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Just a quick FYI regarding the div id is that it wasn't actually a space included, it was just sloppy example-writing from me :) But this presents me with another issue, since I haven't written the code myself. They do not use any value for option. Could you elaborate on why .text shouldn't be used? I think using .text might be my option as this point as I do not have access to changing the code.

Comment: Oh, you don not have access to the html, well...You can get the text (innerHtml) of an option tag because you can get the innerHtml of every html tag. But that doesn't mean you should use the innerHtml. The text is just a visual represantation that looks apealing to the user but it has nothing to do with the logic of you code. That is why the option tag has the value attribute. This way you can seperate the visual and user-appealing part from the data. And you should always aim for that. Always seperate the visual part from the internal data part. But you probably have to use text after all...

Comment: Also, should I really be using var selects = document.getElementById("myselect");? can't seem to get this working when I try it out. Since I want to be getting the option-value that is inside the div, sure, but it doesn't seem to work. The value is returned as "undefined. Maybe somehow I can use document.getElementsByTagName("select")? Because I get using [0] to work, but I do not know how to get the other two with one code.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought you may play around with the selector. try this to get the element: var selects = document.querySelector("#selection1 select") I will update the answer...